# scalaxb.toXML and XML character reference

Tags: scala, scalaxb

I use scalaxb.toXML to parse an object to xml and send it using soap.

When I have [XML character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#NT-CharRef) in some string property, scalaxb.toXML encodes even the XML character.

How to avoid the encode of XML characters? Or escape it?

My string: `Cancellation Fees &#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa; - Until 30 days before departure: 20% of the product price`

My result (cleaned up):

```
<soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...>
    ...
    <mbm:order-remark text="Cancellation Fees &amp;#xd;&amp;#xa;&amp;#xd;&amp;#xa; - Until 30 days before departure: 20% of the product price" position="0" />
    ...
</soap11:Envelope>
```

Each `&` is being encoded to `&amp;` to avoid structural problems with my XML, even when they are valid.

How I call scalaxb.toXML:

```
scalaxb.toXML(obj, namespace, elementLabel, scope)
```

Comment: `&` should be encoded in XML according to the standard. I think you only can replace you XML, bad it seems as a bad idea

Comment: Hi @MikhailIonkin even when the `&` is folowed by a valid sequence? `&#xd;&#xa;` is the XML representation for `\r\n`. Thanks for your quick answer